# Can't add new post in heroku after heroku run rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I recently uploaded my [Rails App](http://banglarpothik.herokuapp.com/) in heroku. I have 3 models -

- User
- Post
- District

I performed the steps required to deploy an app to heroku. My devise user model and district model CRUD are working fine. So I guess my database migration in heroku worked perfectly. But when I try to write a new post in heroku it gives me error "We're sorry, but something went wrong.". I can write new post in localhost without any error.

posts_controller.rb

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show, :index]

    # GET /posts
    # GET /posts.json
    def index
      if params[:tag]
        @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
      else
        @posts = Post.all
      end    
    end

    # GET /posts/1
    # GET /posts/1.json
    def show
    end

    # GET /posts/new
    def new
      @post = Post.new
    end

    # GET /posts/1/edit
    def edit
    end

    # POST /posts
    # POST /posts.json
    def create
      @post = Post.new(post_params)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @post.save
          format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
    # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
    def update
      respond_to do |format|
        if @post.update(post_params)
          format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # DELETE /posts/1
    # DELETE /posts/1.json
    def destroy
      @post.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end

    private
      # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
      def set_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      end

      # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
      def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :tag_list, :location, :body, :user_id, :published)
      end
  end
```

_form.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
      <% if @post.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :tag_list, 'Insert Tags' %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :location %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :location %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :body %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :published %><br>
        <%= f.check_box :published %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: I just tested the app and can confirm the error. Your code looks good - the question then is do you have any logs we could see? You can do this by typing in your console `heroku logs --trace` or by installing the [LogEntries](https://addons.heroku.com/logentries) add-on

Comment: "heroku logs --trace" gave me error  '!Invalid argument: "--trace"'. So I ran "heroku logs" only and came up with this log http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=xbBkK934 .

Comment: Sorrrry - I'm still a little sleepy!

Comment: Hmmm can't see the error in there. Are you sure you're calling the logs as soon as the error happens? I have recently made a gem which allows you to store the error in the db if you'd like to try that?

Comment: Yes I called the logs as soon as the error happened, I myself checked for error in specific time but found nothing too.

Comment: Hmmmmm. Would you like me to share the gem I made to send the error to a database?

Comment: thnks, that would be great i guess!

Comment: No problem - let me write it for you!

Answer (score 2):

In response to your comments, you may be better saving the errors to the DB so you can see the actual exception. To do this, you basically need a db called `errors`, some [middleware](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler/blob/master/lib/exception_handler/parser.rb) & then call:

```
$ heroku rails c
$ errors = Error.last #-> shows latest error
$ errors.inspect()
```

---

**Problem**

I personally think your problem is that you're trying to do something wacky with the `Post.create` method. Specifically, I believe you may have an issue in your `model` preventing the save mechanism to finish without raising an exception.

As mentioned, your `controller` code looks good - so the issue is evidently with another part of your app (typically the `model` or `db`). To resolve this, I would look at your model & then **ensure your db has the required columns** to allow you to save your data correctly.

...

---

**Exceptions**

A good thing for you is to *catch* exceptions.

You can do this in two ways:

> - Save the error to your DB
> - Send the error to your email

I've made a gem for sending the error to your db, but something you will definitely benefit from (which is what we use in production) is to use [`exception_notification`](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification), a maintained gem to help you send the exception to your email:

```
#Gemfile
gem 'exception_notification', '~> 4.0.1'

#config/environments/production.rb
#Use Gmail's server for now
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "domain.com",
  :user_name            => "your_name@gmail.com",
  :password             => Rails.application.secrets.gmail,
  :authentication       => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}  

config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
  :email => {
    :email_prefix => "Error",
    :sender_address => %{"notifier" <error@xxxxxxxxxxxx.com>},
    :exception_recipients => %w{support@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com}
}
```

This should send the error stack trace to your email (we use this in production, so it should work for you too)

--

**Gem**

We've actually made a gem to do this called [`exception_handler`](https://rubygems.org/gems/exception_handler) ([github repo](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler)) - if you put this into your app, it will allow you to save the errors to your db (it also shows custom error pages in production, which should show you what the error is):

```
#Gemfile
gem 'exception_handler'

#cmd
$ rails generate exception_handler:install #-> creates initializer
$ rails generate exception_handler:migration '-> creates "errors" db
$ rake db:migrate

#config/initializers/exception_handler.rb

#DB - 
#Options = false / true
config.db = true #-> set to true

#Social
    #Change these if you want
config.social = {
    twitter:    "http://twitter.com/frontlineutils",
    facebook:   "https://facebook.com/frontline.utilities",
    linkedin:   "https://linkedin.com/company/frontline-utilities",
    youtube:    "https://youtube.com/user/frontlineutils",
    fusion:     "http://frontlinefusion.com/frontlineutils"
}
```

This should work to show the errors for you, then we can better act on them :)

Comment: ok I will let you know what happens after trying this. Thanks for all the helps.

Comment: No problem! It's annoying when you can't see what's going on

Comment: ok I tried both aproach, in case of 'Send the error to your email' no mail is sent to my specified email(I checked spam too). Maybe I did something wrong, please have a look at this http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0CP8k3CL

Comment: and in case of 'Save the error to your DB' returns 'NameError: uninitialized constant Error' when I run "errors = Error.last" in heroku rails console. Seems like I have to initialize an Error class and load it to my environment. If so, how to create the Error.rb?

Comment: You'll need to use `ExceptionHandler::Error`, sorry

Comment: In regards to the email, have you set your password in the `config/secrets.yml` file?

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me quite frequently when running migrations in production on Heroku.  I'd suggest running `heroku pg:reset DATABASE`.  In Heroku, you do not have permission to drop and create the database as the PostgreSQL user you are assigned.  But running this command will run these exact steps for you via Heroku instead of the PostgreSQL way.

Check out [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) for more info.

Comment: bummer, I'll let you know if I think of anything else.  Keep us posted on the results of Rich Peck's suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes (just sometimes) restarting the server works: `heroku restart`

Comment: Ah, I guess it isn't that kind of problem. Anyway I tried restarting server and it didn't work. Thanks for suggesting.